# How to install a New theme in magento 2.0.2

Tags: magento2, theme

I have worked in magento 1.8.Now I have installed magento 2.0.2 in localhost.I have one theme named Ultimo which i want to apply in magento 2.0.2.This theme is not from magentocommerce.com.

I cant see My theme name here.

[image: I cant see My theme name here.]

Then How to select theme from here? What are the steps to apply a theme?

I have tried all the steps from http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html more than one time.But still not working.

Here are all my files.

**theme.xml**

Path : D:/wamp/www/testsite/app/design/frontend/Magento/ultimo/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Ultimo</title>
    <parent>Magento/ultimo</parent>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```

**composer.json**

Path: D:/wamp/www/testsite/app/design/frontend/Magento/ultimo/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "magento/ultimo",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/theme-frontend-luma": "100.0.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-theme",
    "version": "100.0.2",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

**registration.php**

Path : Path: D:/wamp/www/testsite/app/design/frontend/Magento/ultimo/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Magento/ultimo',
    __DIR__
);?>
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: It's seem that you are trying to install Magento 1.x theme in Magento 2.x, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Copy the Ultimo files to directory and  run the Commands below in the order given consecutively:

1. `php bin/magento module:enable Infortis_Base Infortis_Brands Infortis_Cgen Infortis_Dataporter Infortis_Infortis Infortis_Ultimo Infortis_UltraMegamenu Infortis_UltraSlideshow`
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
4. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference magento2 docs file from here,
you have to go step by step using this docs,
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

in your `theme.xml` file,

```
parent tag must be <parent>Magento/blank</parent> or <parent>Magento/luma</parent>
```

Because already two themes are installed in magento 2. so you can extends one of those theme.

Another step is:
Go to `magento2/dev/tools/grunt/configs/theme.js`

add below code after

```
luma: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Magento/luma',
        locale: 'en_US',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
```

setup your custom theme code declaration,

```
ultimo: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'Magento/ultimo',
    locale: 'en_US',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```

Now remove var folder from root , refresh cache  and apply command in cli from root,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

set developer mode using cli,

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Now your theme are display inside admin.
Thanks.

Comment: Please look at my edited question and answer me if i did any mistake in code.

Comment: If I change <parent>Magento/ultimo</parent> to <parent>Magento/blank</parent>.Then "There has been an error processing your request.Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.Error log record number: 1821599746" error occures.

Comment: Whn I apply above command in command promt, this error is shown.'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

**Please place your theme directory under app/design/**

Please remove var directory and pub/static/frontend/content  from magento folder
then use this commands in cmd.
php bin/magento setup:cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy